# WSO2 Iterate mediator query

Tags: java, wso2-esb

Actually I'm using a proxy service and have given a gist of it which is as below:-

```
  <iterator>
            <target>
                 <sequence>
                                <class name="mediator.code.SampleCustomMediator"></class>
                                <log level="full" separator=",**after updatedb call**">
                                <property name="Response" expression="get-property('status')"></property>
                                </log>

                 </sequence>
                 </target>
                 </iterator>




Class mediator code;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SampleCustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {
String updateQuery = "Update Table.440 Set DSP = '"+DSP+"',USER = '"+USER+"',PID = '"+PID+"',PMJ="+PMJ+",PMT="+PMT+" Where DSP<>'Y' AND PO='"+PO+"' AND PD='"+PD+"' AND SD="+SD;
                System.out.println("Query String: "+updateQuery);
                result = stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                if(result>0){
                    String response = "successfully updated "+result+" rows";
                    System.out.println("successfully added "+result);
                    context.setProperty("status",response);
                    return true;
                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("failed");
                    context.setProperty("status","0 rows were updated");
                    return true;
                }           
                }
```

The proxy is working fine.

But ,not able to log the value of Response.

Every time it's showing as null.

I want to see the value of Response everytime when the iterator mediator will get execute.

I've tried with "$ctx:status",payloadFactory mediator(using the same expression at args).

But it doesn't work.

How will I do it?

Comment: how do you create context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 mapping issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744301/wso2-mapping-issue)

Comment: Your mediator class is a fragment of java code,  how have you defined the 'mediate' method, where does the 'stmt' comes from, have you used try / catch that could explain that the "if(result>0)" is never executed ?

Comment: duplicate. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745107/output-of-java-code-is-not-getting-in-wso2-logs

Comment: this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745107/output-of-java-code-is-not-getting-in-wso2-logs, he do not want to log from the java part, just initialize a property that can be used inside his mediation (ok, in log mediator, but it doesn't matter)